# Pandas Indexing Creates ERROR ( Result = self._data[key] ): HEELP

Tags: python, pandas, eclipse, analytics

Error when using Pandas and indexing. why?
**I even asked Derek Banas and he wasn't sure why didn't work so please help**
Errors at bottom in 'quote format'

**This my code:**

```
import numpy as np 

import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data as web
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
%matplotlib inline

import datetime as dt #For defining dates
import mplfinance as mpf # Matplotlib finance

import time
import yfinance as yf;
# Used to get data from a directory
import os
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 5);
#Statsmodels is a great library we can use to run regressions.
import statsmodels.api as sm
# Seaborn extends the capabilities of Matplotlib
import seaborn as sns
# Used for calculating regressions
from statsmodels.tsa.ar_model import AutoReg, ar_select_order

msft= yf.download(tickers='MSFT', period = '1mo',interval = '5m');
x = msft.index; close = msft.index['Adj Close'], high = msft['High']; low = msft['Low']; openprice=msft['Open'];
#print(x); print(high);

print(msft)
```

Error is:

> x = msft.index; close = msft.index['Adj Close'];
>
> ---- " [my addrs]...\pandas\core\indexes\extension.py, line 238 in getitem
>
> result = self._data[key] Following a tutorial
> https://youtu.be/boouvnzw-G8?t=582

I'm using Eclipse on windows. Why doesn't Python work when I index whatever's in the video? Appreciate it, I'm a lowly student and cannot figure why my copy-paste of the github repositry code won't work. **I even asked Derek Banas and he wasn't sure why didn't work so please help**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `msft.index` is a **an index** not a column of your DataFrame.  Whereas you are trying to access it as if it is a column (`msft.index[<ColumnName>]`).
**It should be simply `msft[<ColumnName>]`**.  See below for details:

Run:

```py
msft= yf.download(tickers='MSFT', period = '1mo',interval = '5m');
type(msft.index)
```

Output:

```
pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex
```

---

Run:

```py
msft.head()
```

Output:

```
                            Open       High         Low        Close        Adj Close   Volume
Datetime                        
2021-11-04 09:30:00-04:00   332.890015  333.239990  329.640015  330.549988  330.549988  1619634
2021-11-04 09:35:00-04:00   330.000000  330.589996  329.859985  330.390015  330.390015  966856
2021-11-04 09:40:00-04:00   330.500000  332.299988  330.450104  332.269989  332.269989  760918
2021-11-04 09:45:00-04:00   332.250000  333.100006  332.170013  332.989990  332.989990  526600
2021-11-04 09:50:00-04:00   332.750000  333.179993  332.510010  333.174988  333.174988  498996
```

#### You need to access it this way (get rid of **`.index`**):

Run:

```py
msft['Adj Close']
```

Output:

```
Datetime
2021-11-04 09:30:00-04:00    330.549988
2021-11-04 09:35:00-04:00    330.390015
2021-11-04 09:40:00-04:00    332.269989
2021-11-04 09:45:00-04:00    332.989990
2021-11-04 09:50:00-04:00    333.174988
                                ...    
2021-12-03 15:35:00-05:00    320.594604
2021-12-03 15:40:00-05:00    320.304993
2021-12-03 15:45:00-05:00    320.317505
2021-12-03 15:50:00-05:00    321.679993
2021-12-03 15:55:00-05:00    323.149994
Name: Adj Close, Length: 1603, dtype: float64
```

---

I'm guessing this error was the result of a copy/paste typo (because the video does not have it as you do with `.index`).

I would strongly echo the advise of @WesleyJonCheek : "**One statement per line**"

Comment: thank you both so, so much! I don't quite get why this works but I deeply thank you both :3

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a formatting issue..
Change this line

```py
x = msft.index; close = msft.index['Adj Close'], high = msft['High']; low = msft['Low']; openprice=msft['Open'];
```

to this:

```py
x = msft.index
# THIS LINE CAUSES THE ERROR
# close = msft.index['Adj Close']
close = msft['Adj Close']
high = msft['High'] 
low = msft['Low']
openprice=msft['Open']
```

Tip 1: No need for ; anywhere. Remove them.

Tip 2: One statement per line.

Comment: that doesnt work.  The formatting of this comment will drive mods nutz but here goes: The new series of errors are:
"    close = msft.index['Adj Close'];"
"    result = self._data[key]" in pandas\core\indexes\extension.py, line 238
"    result = super().__getitem__(key)" in pandas\core\arrays\datetimelike.py in __getitem__", line 281
    result = self._ndarray[key]" in core\arrays\mixins.py line 229 in __getitem__"

Will these things just not work in an IDE on a harddrive? does it only function in online interpretors like Jupyter? that'd be stupid but who am I to say?

Comment: Oops, I should have looked closer. Besides for the formatting issues I mentioned, remove the .index part. `close = msft["Adj Close"]`

When you call msft.index you are retrieving the index of msft, but "Adj Close" is a column, so you get this error.